# How do I convert field to time

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to convert a field containing times to 3 columns.  I do not have control over the data as it resides in a linked read only table from a vendor.  The data looks like:

Time

09:00 am - 10:00 am PST

0800 am - 10:00 am EST

I would like it to be 3 fields for start, and end timezone if possible.  Any help would be appreciated.

I've been trying to parse the field using statements like this but I have not been successful getting all 3 separated.

```
select parse('09:30 am' as time) as time_value
```

| Time |
| --- |
| 09:00 am - 10:00 am PST |
| 09:00 am - 10:00 am PST |
| 12:00 pm - 01:00 pm EST |
| 10:00 am - 11:00 am PST |
| 10:00 am - 11:00 am PST |
| 10:00 am - 11:00 am PST |
| 01:00 pm - 02:00 pm EST |
| 10:00 am - 11:00 am PST |
| 10:00 am - 11:00 am PST |
| 10:00 am - 11:00 am PST |
| 01:00 pm - 02:00 pm EST |
| 01:00 pm - 02:00 pm EST |
| 10:00 am - 11:00 am PST |
| 10:00 am - 11:00 am PST |
| 10:00 am - 11:00 am PST |
| 11:00 am - 12:00 pm PST |
| 10:00 am - 11:00 am PST |
| 10:00 am - 11:00 am PST |
| 10:00 am - 11:00 am PST |
| 10:00 am - 11:00 am PST |

I would like the format to be

| StartTime | EndTime | TimeZone |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 9:00 | 10:00 | PST |
| 9:00 | 10:00 | PST |
| 12:00 | 1:00 | EST |
| 10:00 | 11:00 | PST |
| 10:00 | 11:00 | PST |
| 10:00 | 11:00 | PST |
| 1:00 | 2:00 | EST |
| 10:00 | 11:00 | PST |
| 10:00 | 11:00 | PST |
| 10:00 | 11:00 | PST |
| 1:00 | 2:00 | EST |
| 1:00 | 2:00 | EST |
| 10:00 | 11:00 | PST |
| 10:00 | 11:00 | PST |
| 10:00 | 11:00 | PST |
| 11:00 | 12:00 | PST |
| 10:00 | 11:00 | PST |
| 10:00 | 11:00 | PST |
| 10:00 | 11:00 | PST |
| 10:00 | 11:00 | PST |

Comment: Please provide sample input and expected outcome as tables.

Comment: T-SQL is generally very bad at this kind of thing. I'd be tempted to write a C# program that reads the data out processes it an puts it back in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With just a bit of string manipulation

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([Time] varchar(50))  Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 ('09:00 am - 10:00 am PST')
,('09:00 am - 10:00 am PST')
,('12:00 pm - 01:00 pm EST')
 
Select * 
      ,StartTime = try_convert(time,substring([Time],1 ,8))
      ,EndTime   = try_convert(time,substring([Time],12,8))
      ,TimeZone  = right([Time],3)
 From @YourTable
```

**Results**

[image]